# Global MouseMove problem in AS3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I need to register mouse movement for a screensaver like feature. The code below works fine but the mouse move event is not triggered when the mouse is over a movieclip that has had an external swf loaded into it with URLRequest. Is there any way around this without modifying the code in the external swf?

```
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE,function(e){
    lastMoveTime=getTimer()
    trace(stage.mouseX)
})
```

UPDATE:

I need interactivity to be retained in both the parent and child swfs.

The child swf is AS2.

Here is the code for loading the AS2 swf:

```
var sendPane = new Loader(); 
var url:URLRequest = new URLRequest("info.swf"); 
sendPane.load(url); 
addChild(sendPane);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of listening to MOUSE_MOVE events, you could rewrite your code to use a Timer with a delay of 10msecs and listen to the TIMER event. 
In the handler check if the mousepos has changed since last call.
This is not a very nice solution, but the combination of AS3 and AS2 movies makes it necessary.

```
var lastPos:Point = new Point(stage.mouseX, stage.mouseY);
var lastMoveTime:int;
var timer:Timer = new Timer(10, 0);
timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, handleTimer);
timer.start();

private function handleTimer(e:TimerEvent):void
{
    if (lastPos.x!=stage.mouseX || lastPos.y!=stage.mouseY) lastMoveTime = getTimer();
    lastPos = new Point(stage.mouseX, stage.mouseY);
}
```

Comment: Clever and hacky! I like it! Surprisingly I might still need to do this as I never got a fix for that bug. Luckily the client hasnt noticed yet! Thanks again @Reiner

Answer (score 1):

set the loading container to `loader.mouseChildren = false;` or `loader.mouseEnabled = false;`

Or you can add a Sprite or Movieclip on top of the stage with `sprite.alpha = 0` and draw it as large as the stage. then add the mouse listener to this Sprite.

```
var s:Sprite = new Sprite();
s.graphics.beginFill(0, 0);
s.graphics.drawRectangle(0, 0, stage.stageWidth, stage.stageHeight);
s.endFill();
s.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, listener);

addChild(s);
```

Booth versions this stops the loaded swf from reacting to the mouse. But you said screensaver, so I thought this is okay.

Comment: Thanks. Will your first suggestion not disable all mouse events (click rollover etc) in the external swf?

Comment: Thanks @DanielB but it's actually an interactive system that resets after a set period of inactivity, so I need to retain interactivity.

Comment: Are you loading an AS2 swf? for AS3 stage should receive the mouse move event. Have you tried to add the listener to the loader itself?

Comment: Yeah it's an AS2 swf. I'll try attaching the listener to the loader as well as the stage

Comment: Bummer - No joy attaching the listener to the loader MovieClip. Any other ideas?

Comment: last one: AVM1Movie(loader.content).addEventListener( ... )

Comment: hmm, tried this but got a classic null object reference error:
`AVM1Movie(sendPane.content).addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, function(e){
  lastMoveTime=getTimer();
  trace(mouseX)
 })`

Comment: you can add the listener only if the loader has completeley loaded and sendPane.content is not null. but i looked in the reference and it seems AVM1Move does not has mouse events ;-( sry.

Comment: ah ok Thanks for the effort @DanielB